# Tur CM 123:16: "שאין לך מציל ממון חבירו"

Tags: translation, tur

I'm struggling with one particular phrase in the Tur ([CM 123:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Tur%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.123.16?lang=bi)). Most of it is clear until we get to:

> אבל אם התובע במדינה זו והנתבע במדינה אחרת הרי זה עושה מצוה שאין לך
>   מציל ממון חבירו גדול מזה שאם אי אתה אומר כך כל אחד יטול ממון חבירו
>   וילך למדינת הים:

I've got as far as: *But if the plaintiff is in this country and the defendant is in a different country, behold one does a mitzvah...* and there I'm lost. I think it's the phrase "שאין לך מציל ממון חבירו" that's foxing me. Looking for it in similar texts (eg Radak to Genesis 14:20) reveals it's something to do with a 'finder's fee' but this doesn't assist much.

Can anyone help?

Comment: אין לך מציל ממון חברו גדול מזה. There is no great matsil mamon chavero as this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My translation:

> But if the plaintiff is in this country and the defendant is in a different country, then he [the one acting as an agent of the plaintiff] performs a *mitzvah*, because there is no greater case than this of saving his fellow's money. For, were this not the case, anyone could take his fellow's money and abscond abroad.

Comment: This makes perfect sense! Thank you. I'd not linked the גדול מזה with the אין לך in my head.